# Gremlin-Lambda - how to automate graph creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin

I would like to create graph with Lambda to automate it.

This my code

```
    from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility
    
    from gremlin_python import statics
    from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
    from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
    from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
    from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        graph = Graph()
        remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection('wss://myEndPoint:8182/gremlin','g')
        g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)
        
        print(g.V().toList())
        print(g.V().elementMap().toList())
        print(g.V().has('name','myName').inE().outV().elementMap().toList())
        print(g.V().has('name','myName').outE().inV().elementMap().toList())
        remoteConn.close()
```

I used the code posted on [this link](https://github.com/hardikvasa/database-journal/blob/master/code-samples/aws_neptune.py)
I used simple graph command to test it
Form result tab I see the correct data, but I don't see the graphs

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is rather general. Can you tell us what you have tried and what _specific_ problem you are experiencing? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My idea is to use an AWS Lambda. With python I want to connect to neptune AWS DB and I want to create graph with gremlin query. I created with notebook specific queries with gremlin. For some queries I need to pass a parameter to create a specific graph

Comment: If you have some code that is not working, feel free to add the code to your Question and tell us the _specific_ problem you are having, with the error message if appropriate. This will get a response much better than a "How do I?" type of question.

Comment: I found some examples, but I didn't find what I need. I wish I had some suggestions for the correct way to accomplish what I want

Comment: You say that you want to "want to connect to neptune AWS DB". Did you attempt to connect to it? You would need to use the [boto3 Amazon Neptune library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/neptune.html).

Comment: Thanks, now I want to create graphs like I just did with the notebook. How can I do this?

Comment: How did you do it with the notebook?

Comment: I did it with neptune notebook, and with gremlin commands. For example: %%gremlin -d name
g.V().has('name','my_name').inE().outV().path().by(elementMap()). With this, I have my graph

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I would like to create a web app to create the charts. I tried using your link with python script on ec2, but I have a problem with one package

Comment: Creating remote connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neptune.py", line 133, in <module>
    conn = create_remote_connection()
  File "neptune.py", line 119, in create_remote_connection
    connection_string(),
  File "neptune.py", line 126, in connection_string
    database_url = 'wss://{}:{}/gremlin'.format(os.environ['myneptune.eu-central-1.neptune.amazonaws.com'], os.environ['8182'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'test-myneptune-central-1.neptune.amazonaws.com'

Comment: Now I have this error. I solved the above problem with DB connection.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gremlinexample.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 63, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)

Comment: File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tkinter

Comment: Please Edit your question to add details rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples in the documentation of using Lambda to connect to Neptune in various runtimes.  Python included here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html#lambda-functions-examples-python

This also includes the proper connection handling and retry methods.

This could be used as a template for passing any Gremlin query.

If you've never used Lambda before, I would suggest going through some of the getting started exercises there to familiarize yourself with the service.  Here's a quick "Hello World" tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/run-serverless-code/

Comment: I created a python lambda, but I have a problem with an import module: "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'backoff'"

Comment: I resolved the issue for modules import. Now I have a new issue: "errorMessage": "2022-12-21T10:27:40.505Z 54bcaf8c-9934-4361-acfa-2b14e1c2ff58 Task timed out after 50.05 seconds"

Comment: I resolved my issues, now I want to draw the graph. I see only the data in my response. Where I can see them?

Comment: When you saw "draw", are you referring to creating a visualization? What is the intent of the visualization? Is it just for individual analysis or do you want to provide some sort of interface to a user (web or otherwise)?  And how large will the visualization be (100s/1000s of nodes/edges or millions)?

Comment: Thanks @Taylor, I intend to display a graph on a static web page on S3 for example where I can upload the graph every day. I want, for now, an easy way to do this

Comment: I'm checking if I can share a notebook with a remote user. The notebook should not be modified by users